# Analytics Multiple Domain Goal Tracking

Tags: google-analytics

Hi I need help tracking Google Analytics goals on multiple domain. Here's the scenario:

```
step 1: website1.com
step 2: website2.com/register/register.php (with membership form)
step 3: website2.com/register/payment/signup.php (with Credit Card payment form)
```

Success URL: website2.com/register/success.php

Here's how I set it up:

On website 1:

```
 _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-#######-##']);
    _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
    _gaq.push(['_setAllowHash', false]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

*** I also add the _link() method on the link that sends users to website2.com.

On Website 2 (membership form):

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-#######-##']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowHash', false]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/register-user']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', location.hostname]);
```

I got stuck on website2.com (payment page)

what code do I put there so I can track goals. Also do I need to use the _linkByPost() method for the membership form? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of the array with  `_trackPageview` sets the url.  More than likely both of your page hits come in as `/register-user` instead of the `/register/register.php` and `/register/payment/signup.php` on website2.com.  Change that line to:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

The following line duplicates default functionality and can be removed:

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', location.hostname]);
```

The following line is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageLoadTime) and can be removed.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']);
```

Comment: Did you mean `_setAllowHash` has been depricated (not `_setDomainName`)?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that register and payment pages have parameters in URL like this:
'website2.com/register/register.php?user=948aohgaawgwignwg
website2.com/register/payment/register.php?user=948aohgaawgwignwg'
How do I set the goal funnels using Regex?

Comment: @mike, comment was for line below. Updated answer for clarity